# Using awk to print at a certain location in the file opened

Tags: awk

```
awk -v sep="$FILE_DELIM" -v pb="$P_KEY"  'BEGIN{FS=sep} {print $0 FS pb FS "'"$A"'" FS "'"$B"'"}' $DATA_FILE > ${DATA_FILE}.${LNUM}

mv ${DATA_FILE}.${LNUM} $DATA_FILE
```

Consider I have a pipe(|) delimited file which contains one record like:

```
abc|123|pqr|456
```

In this case, I am passing $FILE_DELIM as | (pipe symbol). The awk command prints $P_KEY, $A, $B at the end of the said file, assuming $P_KEY = key123, $A = A and $B = B the output looks something like:

```
abc|123|pqr|456**|key123|A|B**
```

Instead, I want the output to look like this:

```
abc|123|pqr**|key123|A|B**|456
```

I want to print the same 3 fields ($P_KEY, $A, $B) after a certain number of fields, in this case, after "abc", "123" and "pqr" appear, that is at the fourth position.

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for adding your efforts in form of code in your question. Could you please do clarify your question(by editing it) a bit more as of now its not that clear, thank you.

Comment: Why do you not use "`-v A="..." -v B="..."` like `P_KEY` parameter ?

Comment: Do not print whole line with `$0`. Your output FS is the same value than FS. Use : `awk -v sep="$FILE_DELIM" -v pb="$P_KEY" -v A="$A" -v B="$B"  'BEGIN{FS=sep; OFS=FS} {print $1, $2, $3 "**", pb, A, B "**", $4}' $DATA_FILE`